# Django: Turn QuerySet in Dictionary before rendering

Tags: python, django

I would like to render a QuerySet because it would be easy to render in templates.
However, I am struggling to build the right one.

So, I decided to build a dictionary and render it.
Is that a Django way of doing?

Here is a simple app which associates instances of Application with instances of Event.

Purpose : let managers know status of applications on production.

An event is pending when it 'status_end' properties is Null.
Each new 'event' associated with an 'application' would close the last event by filling the 'status_end' value.
Application without open event are all status OK!

Here is a part of the model :

```
class Application(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Event(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('OK', 'OK'),
        ('KO', 'KO'),
    )
    app = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_start = models.DateTimeField()
    status_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    status_global = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default='OK')
```

Usually, in my views, I render QuerySet.
But in this case, there is some more processing.

So, in my views.py, I wrote a view that would render a dictionnary.

```
def dashboard_appstat(request):
    answer = []
    for app in Application.objects.all():
        try:
            # one event still running.
            open_event = app.event_set.get(status_end__isnull=True)
            answer.append({'app': app.app_name, 'status_global': open_event.status_global,\
            'status_bdd': open_event.status_bdd, 'status_batch': open_event.status_batch,\
            'status_comment': open_event.status_comment, 'status_start': open_event.status_start})
        except Event.DoesNotExist as e:
            # All events are closed
            answer.append({'app': app.app_name, 'status_global': 'OK',
            'status_bdd': 'OK', 'status_batch': 'OK',\
            'status_comment': '', 'status_start': ''})
        except Event.MultipleObjectsReturned as e:
            # Business rule in models.py must avoid this
            print('NOT GOOD', type(e).__name__)
        print(answer)

    context = {'answer': answer}
    return render(request, 'appstat/dashboard_appstat.html', context)
```

Well, I works.
I can also do it with a sql query. But I doubt that's 'Djangonic'...

Comment: the closest you can get is probably using `values()` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: Did you think about putting (at least the logic) as a property or method into the model?

Answer (score 0):

@yedpodtrzitko and @Jann : thanks for your help.

yedpodtrzitko is indeed close to the way I did it - but his way is more elegant.
Finally, I implemented Jann proposal : use a 'model method'.

models.py :

```
class Application(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def get_last_status(self):
        """ get last Event object associated with this application """
        last_event = self.event_set.order_by('-status_start')[0]
        return last_event

class Event(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('OK', 'OK'),
        ('KO', 'KO'),
    )
    app = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_start = models.DateTimeField()
    status_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    status_global = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default='OK')
```

views.py :

```
def dashboard_appstat(request):
    apps_querysset = Application.objects.all()
    context = {'apps_querysset': apps_querysset}
    return render(request, 'appstat/dashboard_appstat.html', context)
```

In template, the properties of an Event instance associated with an Application instance can be accessed like this 
(NOTE : `app.get_last_status().status_global` won't work!) :

```
{% if app.get_last_status.status_end != None %}
..... html .....
{% elif app.get_last_status.status_global == 'OK' %}
..... html .....
{% elif app.get_last_status.status_global == 'KO' %}
..... html .....
{% endif %}
```

This is much more 'djangonic', I guess. And more concise.

Man has to think the Django way. But the dictionary way is somewhere quite convenient and also a structure Python developers are confortable with.

Do you sometimes use the dictionary way?